# What is the default password for connecting to tarantool cartridge application

Tags: tarantool, tarantool-cartridge

I have a default application on tarantool cartridge (cluster).
I want to connect to the cluster's router. I use the command:

```
tarantoolctl connect admin:_password_@localhost:3301
```

Where can I find the default password?

Answer (score 9):

In cartridge it is called `cluster_cookie`. You may find the default one [here](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge/blob/master/cartridge.lua#L45).

If you've created your project using `cartridge-cli` tool it would depend on your [project name](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-cli/blob/3575ac49cb3f6680e9ab8459df73ce6a95593170/cartridge-cli/templates/cartridge/files/app_files.lua#L105):

```
...
cluster_cookie = '${project_name_lower}-cluster-cookie'
...
```

And you can manipulate its value from [`cartridge-cli`](https://github.com/tarantool/cartridge-cli#usage-example) config

Also, there is an example for [`ansible-cartridge`](https://github.com/tarantool/ansible-cartridge#usage-example) role config.